# Does ++(prefix) return lvalue?

Tags: c, prefix

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int a=1;
 printf("%d",(++a)++); 
 return 0;
}
```

This code gives an error

```
error: invalid lvalue in increment
```

Is it that ++a does not return l-value that is required by ++(postfix) operator to deal with?
if yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, increment and decrement operators (like all operators except unary `*` and `[]`) return non-lvalue values.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: My answer is incorrect. As pointed out, increment and decrement operators don't return lvalues.**

The problem here is that you are abusing [sequence points](http://c-faq.com/expr/seqpoints.html). When you try to modify the value of a variable in one statement using both the post and prefix increment operator you end up creating a situation in which the values of each sequence point is dependent upon the other. So the expression is invalid.

Comment: Sequence points are really only worth mentioning if the code actually compiles and runs, which this doesn't (due to the not-an-lvalue problem).

Comment: @AndrewMedico Ok, I thought they did return lvalues.